# $r$-dimensional Frobenius coin problem

Tags: arithmetic-geometry

I saw the following result in a paper of Stephenson (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6911.pdf, Lemma $2.2$), which is a variant of the Frobenius coin problem.

Let $n_1, . . . , n_p$ be $p$ non-negative integers and let $d = gcd(n_1, . . . , n_p)$. There exists integers $N_2, . . . , N_p$ such that the set of all sums
$\{ \sum k_i n_i, k_1 \in \mathbb{Z}_+, k_i \in \{0, . . . , N_i\} \forall i \in \{2, . . . , p\} \}$
contains all large enough multiples of $d$.

Is there some $r$-dimensional version of it, in the sense that if one takes $X_1, . . ., X_p \in \mathbb{Z}^r_+$,  there exists $N_2, \ldots, N_p$ such that the set of sums
$\{ \sum k_i X_i, k_1 \in \mathbb{Z}_+, k_i \in \{0, . . . , N_i\} \forall i \in \{2, . . . , p\} \}$
contains all elements of a certain subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^r$ that are in a given affine cone of $\mathbb{N}^r$ ?

Thanks!